# What am I doing wrong? Trying to join two fields from two tables, Drupal 7

Tags: users, search, database

Based on this [tutorial](http://www.mauromascia.com/blog/extending-drupal-search-other-user-fields/?lang=it) I created a module to be able to find first name or lastname from user fields. Everything is working fine, but I notice that the search only looks either for name and last name and not both. Could you please help me to modify the following code to be able to look for both first name and last name? Unfortunately I am not a pro in databases, I know just the basics... I would really appreciate any answer.
Thanks.

```
function custom_extend_user_search_search_execute($keys = NULL, $conditions = NULL) {

   $find = array();
  // Replace wildcards with MySQL/PostgreSQL wildcards.
  $keys = preg_replace('!\*+!', '%', $keys);
  $query = db_select('users', 'u')->extend('PagerDefault');
  $query->distinct();
  $query->fields('u', array('uid'));

  // Additional tables
  $query->join('field_data_field_name_first', 'fn', 'fn.entity_id = u.uid');
  $query->join('field_data_field_name_last', 'ln', 'ln.entity_id = u.uid');

  $query->fields('u', array('mail'));
  $query->condition(
    db_or()
      ->condition('u.name', '%' . db_like($keys) . '%', 'LIKE')
      ->condition('u.mail', '%' . db_like($keys) . '%', 'LIKE')

      // Additional fields
      ->condition('field_name_first_value', '%' . db_like($keys) . '%', 'LIKE')
      ->condition('field_name_last_value', '%' . db_like($keys) . '%', 'LIKE')
  );

  $uids = $query->limit(15)->execute()->fetchCol();
  $accounts = user_load_multiple($uids);

  $results = array();
  foreach ($accounts as $account) {
    $result = array(
      'title' => format_username($account),
      'link' => url('user/' . $account->uid, array('absolute' => TRUE)),
    );
    if (user_access('administer users')) {
      $result['title'] .= ' (' . $account->mail . ')';
    }
    $results[] = $result;
  }

  return $results;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this in a custom module? Why not just use views?

Comment: Because I needed a search box that would display a drop down menu to search for users, content types and nodes. I tried doing that using views but I did not know how those three search conditions and I did not know how to display a dropdown menu either. So I decided to use custom search module and it is actually working fine, but for some reason it is not letting me search for first and last name at the same time.

Comment: I think I should add a  db_and() as well, but don´t know how... I tried add it is right after db_or condition but still it is not working..

Comment: Well, it seems the code should work, but for some reason it is not... I would really appreciate if someone can help me here..